# Time complexity for 3 nested loops with 2 variables

Tags: time-complexity, nested-loops

how to represent the time complexity for the next nested loops when there are 2 variables involved and not just N?

Let's say N=input of the size
And A=some discrete value (relevant quantity)

so for N=50000 and for A=30000

```
for( int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    for( int j=0;j<A;j++ )
    {
       for( int x=0;x<N;x++)
       {
          // do something
          doSomething();
       }
    }
}
```

Could it be O(N^2*A)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, complexity in your case will be `O(N^2*A)`

Comment: Thank you, and if A gets smaller on each iteration? so 1st is 30K then 25K then 20K and so on?

Comment: Well, it depends. We have `N` iterations. How `A` will be changing? Ok, third operation 20K, what will be on 10th operation?

Comment: mmm might be possible the question about A makes no sense because is going down from original value to 0 beginning after 80% processing, so could be useless to be so accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, O(A*N^2). You only neglect lesser terms if they separately impact on time complexity (i.e. "O(A + N^2)" would be O(N^2))